# Generic Input Parameter Compilation Error With Enum

Tags: java, generics, enums, factory

I have a Java Enum Class as below. I am trying to Convert A Type Boolean To B Type. For which I am using factory with Generic. But here code for `getInstance()` method implementation is getting compiled successfully, while `getInstance1()` method implementation is getting failed.

```
public enum FactoryEnum {

    BOOLEAN {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public IConverter<ABoolean, BBoolean> getInstance() {// Compiled Successfully
            return new BooleanConverter();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public IConverter<ABoolean, BBoolean> getInstance(BBoolean bacStacDataType) { // Compilation Failed
            return new BooleanConverter(bacStacDataType);
        }

    };

    public abstract <M extends IADataType, R extends IBDataType> IConverter<M, R> getInstance();

    public abstract <M extends IADataType, R extends IBDataType> IConverter<M, R> getInstance1(R data);


    // A Type
    public interface IADataType {

    }

    public class ABoolean implements IADataType {

    }

    // B Type
    public interface IBDataType {

    }

    public class BBoolean implements IBDataType {

    }

    //Converter to Convert Data From A to B
    public interface IConverter<M, R> {

    }

    public class BooleanConverter implements IConverter<ABoolean, BBoolean> {


        public BooleanConverter() {

        }

        public BooleanConverter(BBoolean boolean1) {

        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to understand the reason behind it? Because same generic Parameter R is being used in return as well in first method, where it is being compiled successfully. But when it is being passed as input parameter, it's being failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This signature:

```
public abstract <M extends IADataType, R extends IBDataType> IConverter<M, R> getInstance1(R data);
```

means that an implementation of that method must take *any* R (within the bound).

You are trying to implement it to take a specific R.

That simply doesn't work, because it's not override-equivalent.

Also, you should be very wary of these `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotations. Only suppress warnings that you can reason are actually safe; these are not.

---

If you want the enum values to have different types, you can't use an enum. Ultimately, enum values are just static final fields in the containing class.

So, just define a class instead, then you can use class-level type variables to constrain to specific types.

```
public class FactoryClass<M extends IADataType, R extends IBDataType> {

    public static final FactoryClass<ABoolean, BBoolean> BOOLEAN = new FactoryClass<ABoolean, BBoolean>() {

        @Override
        public BooleanConverter getInstance() {
            return new BooleanConverter();
        }

        @Override
        public BooleanConverter getInstance(BBoolean bacStacDataType) {
            return new BooleanConverter(bacStacDataType);
        }

    };

    public abstract IConverter<M, R> getInstance();

    public abstract IConverter<M, R> getInstance1(R data);
}
```

Comment: Bit sleepy, but might a `R super BBoolean` allow for compilation?  I'm aware of PECS, just not in the mind to reason it right now.

Comment: @Rogue considering you can't specify a type variable with a lower bound, no. Lower bounds can only be used with wildcards.

Comment: Ah drats, you're right. Thanks for unblurring the lines between wildcards/type variables for me again.